# IDEA IDE: Text cursor movement after "select all"

Tags: intellij-idea, user-experience, editing, usability

I use IDEA IDE (PhpStorm). My regular pattern of keyboard actions is "`Ctrl+A`, `Ctrl+Alt+L`, `ARROW_KEY`" to auto format code in the editor then to remove selection. Some time ago I just pressed any arrow key to move text cursor to one position and to remove selection. Text cursor was moved to one position relative to position where cursor was before I pressed `Ctrl+A`.

But now cursor jumps to begin of selection (`left` or `top` arrow key) or to the end (`right` or `down` arrow key). It means jump to the first character of the code or to the last character. It is very uncomfortable, I need to use touchpad/mouse to remove selection and to stay on the same code fragment.

Is it possible to configure this behaviour (cursor movement for "all is selected" case) in IDEA settings?

Comment: Try not doing ctrl-a first. Try pressing escape instead of arrow.

Comment: thanks, @jackrabbit , `esc` is a way; I can't "not doing ctrl-a first", in some cases auto format acts on changed lines only ("select all" allows to break this)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `editor.action.caretMovement.UpDownIgnoreSelectionBoundaries=true` option in `idea.properties` [IntelliJ platform properties](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/tuning-the-ide.html#configure-platform-properties) file. Then on Up/Down keys caret will navigate to up/down line.